# How to use exec to open Google Chrome

Tags: node.js

In node console:

```
> var a = require('child_process')
> a.execSync('open /Applications/Google Chrome.app')
The files /Applications/Google and /Users/***/Chrome.app do not exist.
Error: Command failed: open /Applications/Google Chrome.app
The files /Applications/Google and /Users/***/Chrome.app do not exist.

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:1339:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:1379:13)
    at repl:1:3
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
>
```

There is a space between Google and Chrome.app. What should I do to make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try putting path between " " characters:

```
var a = require('child_process')
a.execSync('open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"')
```

or between ' ' characters:

```
var a = require('child_process')
a.execSync("open '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'")
```

Escaping space with backslash (\) does not work properly and results in "No such file or directory" error

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this on OSX:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec("open -a 'google chrome'");
```

Note: This works only on OSX.